# ubuntu shell scripting

Tags: process, ubuntu-10.04, shell

I'm new to shell scripting.  I need to write a script that executes this command to get the process ID's for the tasks...

```
ps aux | grep java | grep dbConvert2 | awk '{print $2}'
```

then do some other stuff, and then kill the process ID's that I grabbed earlier...

I know I can do kill -9, i just don't know how to dynamically grab all the PID's and store them as variables

Comment: You really ought to accept more answers to your questions. 27% might scare people away.

Comment: Don't use kill -9 for the first command you always run, in general.  Just use kill and let the program clean itself up.  If kill doesn't work, then fall back to kill -9.  It's like when you go into a store to return something, you don't start shouting at the clerk immediately; you try being nice first, and then start screaming and waving your arms only after they ignore you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

append `| xargs kill -9` to your current command

[edit]
if you want to do some operations on each id, you can use a for loop, something like:

```
for my_pid in `YOUR_CMD`; do
    <some stuff with $my_pid>
    kill -9 $my_pid
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pkill -9 'java.*dbConvert2'
```

You might want to use `pgrep 'pattern'` to try different patterns before.

**Edit:** If your process isn't matched, you might need to use `-f` (applies to both pgrep and pkill, use *after* the -9 though) to search the entire command including arguments.
Example: `pkill -9 -f 'java.*dbConvert2'`

Comment: I am not sure, but is 'pgrep' available with base installation?

Comment: Yes, it's in `procps` which is required. (/bin/kill is in the *same* package)